# Find polynomial for a graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the polynomial for a graph such as

[image]

Clearly we have
$$f(-1)=f(5)=f(9)=0, \qquad f(0)=-3,\, f(2)=-5,\, f(7)=2, \qquad f'(2)=f'(7)=0,$$
but I find the number of constraints too many to find a, e.g. $x^3$ polynomial. Since there are 8 constraints one can find a $x^7$ polynomial;
$$p(x)=-\frac{19 x^7}{112000}+\frac{1069 x^6}{220500}-\frac{59557 x^5}{1176000}+\frac{79087x^4}{352800}-\frac{879899 x^3}{2352000}+\frac{1008509 x^2}{1764000}-\frac{29809x}{16800}-3$$
but cannot a “cleaner” $x^3$ polynomial be fitted as well? TIA.

Comment: What is that diagram from?  Was it from a problem where one was *meant* to identify the polynomial?  It looks subtly non-polynomial to me.

Comment: The graph is from an old test (1990s), and I try to re-draw it with “modern tools” but I would need the explicit function to do that. It could probably be done with Bezier curves, but I thought an explicit function would be a good start.

Comment: How precise should this be?  $-\frac 1{15}(x+1)(x-5)(x-9)$ isn't terrible.

Comment: True, but the answer requires that $f'(2)=0$.